# How do I set up both OSGi and non-OSGi WARs to use an external properties file

Tags: java, spring, configuration, osgi, war

I have a project that uses Spring that may be run as a .war in an OSGi container, namely Karaf, or as a .war in a non-OSGi container, such as Jetty.  The .wars are created by separate Maven projects.

Currently, my project has a properties file that sits inside the .war and is grabbed from the classpath of the .war using a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean in Spring.  We'd like to externalize that properties file.  What is the best/easiest way to set up external properties file(s) for both .wars?

I understand that the OSGi .war could set up our `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean to reference properties files using `osgix:cm-properties`, but I'm not confident that this would also work for the non-OSGi .war. (Or would it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you just need to make sure you have different spring xml files for every combination. 
For Example you have the spring-app.xml file as your central spring configuration file. Now combine it either with a spring-osgi-properties.xml when using the spring extender through the spring manifest entry and a spring-std-properties.xml when used in the std. jetty container.